# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi only activates when restarting

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10 on dual boot. Since the first time I launched Ubuntu I've been having this problem. When I launch, wifi in system settings shows as disabled, and doesn't allow me to enable it. When I close the lid of my laptop and open it again, it inmediately connects to the desired wifi network with no issues.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` (with wifi enabled after restarting)

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of same command after booting, before restarting, without wifi connectivity

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci`.

Comment: @AndroidDev `lspci` is not enough.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: The card seems to be hard blocked meaning that a key pin on the wireless network card does not receive power and therefor the card it deactivated. The pin is usually controlled by a) a physical switch b) indirectly by the BIOS / EFI and some key combination. Your problem indicates case b) and a fault in the firmware. Your first step should be to look for firmware updates for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Open a terminal and try the following:

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`